# How can I play UNNotificationSound.default() by a player in my app?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, uilocalnotification, audiotoolbox

I have a list of ringtones in iOS app, also, one of the options should be the system default ringtone, that the user can select and play. 
How can I obtain the ringtone that user selected and how can I play this ringtone in-app with `AVAudioPlayer`, or at least get the name of the file that was selected by the user?

Comment: Post a notification with only sound.

Comment: @shallowThought I meant to play in app, not to attach to notification.

Answer (score 1):

Add `import AudioToolbox`, then `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(1000))` to play a system sound.

See [Audio Services](https://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices) for a list of sounds. Hopefully, one of those sounds will be the as `UNNotificationSound.default`.

**Edit**

1002 seems to be the correct sound ID for the default notifcation.

Comment: Does that mean if we create a notification with UNNotificationSound.default, it will always play system sound with id 1002 ? Or if we change the textTone in iPhone settings, will it play that tone instead of 1002 for UNNotificationSound.default ?